# Run shell commands on current file based on file extension

Tags: key-bindings, external-command, filetype

I'm currently doing a lot of work with both Ruby and JavaScript. I know that I can run my Ruby files with `:! ruby %` and likewise my JavaScript with `:! node %`, and that I can bind either of those to, eg, `,b`. How can I set things up so that I can just bind a single command that will check the extension of the file I'm editing and run the appropriate command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `:make` for this; you can set `makeprg` (short for make program) to any command.

Some examples:

```
au FileType ruby set makeprg=ruby\ %
au FileType javascript set makeprg=node\ %
au FileType python set makeprg=python\ %
au FileType coffeescript set makeprg=coffee\ -c\ %

noremap ,b :make<CR>
```

`:make` was originally intended to run the `make` tool to build the project, but languages such as Ruby or Javascript don't need compiling, to setting it to something that will run the code makes sense.